# Defining a range within a filtered column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am attempting to make a macro that I can use to automatically select all values within the filtered range of the column. Ideally I am trying to get this to work with 10 filter conditions (1-10), but the number of values returned for these conditions can vary.

I have attached a very small set of sample data of what the columns will look like. I am filtering by the second column "LinSpatialBin". I am attempting to get the average of the values in the last column (LIN event/tracklength) for each filtered condition (e.g. if there are two values returned for spatialbin 1 I want their average in the first cell of the  column to the right). I thought I should use relative references as this needs to work over multiple column ranges in different sheets.

Please let me know if I can provide more details or clarify anything. Below is the script and below that is the sample data.

**Script**

`Sub test()
'
' test Macro
' test
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 5).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="3"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="4"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="5"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="6"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="7"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="8"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="9"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$1142").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="10"
    ActiveCell.Offset(27, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-1]:R[27]C[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
End Sub`

**Sample Data**

```
right_8.1.2017_CTRL_LIN_MTX_2_1_1200FR
LINTrackLINSpatiLIN Beha LIN TraLIN event/tracklength
       1       1       0       0
       2       1       0       0
       3       1       0       0
       4       1       0       0
       5       1       0       0
       6       1       0       0
       7       1       0       0
       8       1       0       0
       9       1       0       0
       1       2       0       0
       2       2       0       0
       3       2       0       0
       4       2       0       0
       5       2       0       5    0.00
       6       2       0       0
       7       2       0       0
       8       2       0       1    0.00
       9       2       0       0
       1       3       0       0
       2       3       0       0
       3       3       0       0
       4       3       0       0
       5       3      22      92    0.24
       6       3       0       0
       7       3       0       6    0.00
       8       3       5      20    0.25
       9       3       0       0
       1       4       0       0
       2       4       0       4    0.00
       3       4       0       0
       4       4       0       0
       5       4       9      58    0.16
       6       4       0       0
       7       4       2      17    0.12
       8       4       0       0
       9       4       1       1    1.00
       1       5       0       0
       2       5       7      53    0.13
       3       5       1       7    0.14
       4       5       0       0
       5       5       0       0
       6       5       1       9    0.11
       7       5       1       5    0.20
       8       5       0       0
       9       5       3      11    0.27
       1       6       0       0
       2       6       1      23    0.04
       3       6       4      16    0.25
       4       6       0       0
       5       6       0       0
       6       6       2      15    0.13
       7       6       0       0
       8       6       0       0
       9       6       0       0
       1       7       3       4    0.75
       2       7       6      29    0.21
       3       7       0       0
       4       7       5      20    0.25
       5       7       0       0
       6       7       0       0
       7       7       0       0
       8       7       0       0
       9       7       0       0
       1       8       2      10    0.20
       2       8       1       5    0.20
       3       8       0       0
       4       8      14      66    0.21
       5       8       0       0
       6       8       0       0
       7       8       0       0
       8       8       0       0
       9       8       0       0
       1       9       1       4    0.25
       2       9       1       7    0.14
       3       9       0       0
       4       9      10      47    0.21
       5       9       0       0
       6       9       0       0
       7       9       0       0
       8       9       0       0
       9       9       0       0
       1      10       1       3    0.33
       2      10       3      10    0.30
       3      10       0       0
       4      10      15      77    0.19
       5      10       0       0
       6      10       0       0
       7      10       0       0
       8      10       0       0
       9      10       0       0
```

Comment: What your code does instead of your goal? What is your exact question?

Answer (score 0):

To select the visible cells....

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`

But this begs the question what do you really want to do with the cells?